# Javascript: Object Array merging on criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following 3 array of objects

```js
let recipients = [{"blackList":"0","clawfulBasis":"3","cmOneID":"0","id":"13251316","jurisdiction":"SCPB - LON","name":"David G","relationshipManager":"Adam Cavalier","subscription":"","_schema":"nms:recipient"},{"blackList":"0","clawfulBasis":"3","cmOneID":"666666","id":"13251376","jurisdiction":"Guernsey","name":"David Llanos Changed Garcia","relationshipManager":"Adam Cavalier","_schema":"nms:recipient"}];

let services = [{"id":"3218143","name":"SVC27","label":"UK &gt; Financial Advisers &gt; Services"},{"id":"3721","name":"newsletter","label":"Newsletter"},{"id":"15656200","name":"SVC35","label":"Sustainability"}]

let serviceSubscriptions =  [{"recipientId":"13251316","serviceId":"3218143"},{"recipientId":"13251376","serviceId":"15656200"},{"recipientId":"13251376","serviceId":"15656200"},{"recipientId":"13251376","serviceId":"3721"}]
```

**serviceSubscriptions** contains recipients that are subscripbed to  services, what I would like to do is enrich the recipient objects to contain their subscriptions something like the below, the `id` attribute of recipient object is the `recipientId` attribute of the serviceSubscriptions and can be used to match.

> {"blackList":"0","clawfulBasis":"3","cmOneID":"666666","id":"13251376","jurisdiction":"Guernsey","name":"David
> Llanos Changed Garcia","relationshipManager":"Adam
> Cavalier","subscriptions":"[3218143,15656200,3721]","_schema":"nms:recipient"}

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudocode, you want to loop through each serviceSubscription. For each serviceSubscription, find the recipient record by `recipientId` and append the `serviceId` to the recipient's `subscriptions` value.

This is quite slow, but you can optimize it based on your needs (how large is serviceSubscription, how large is recipients, etc.). For example, you could modify this by building a hash from serviceSubscriptions where the key is the recipientId and the value is a list of each recipients subscriptions. Then you could simply map through the recipients list, and check if there is a subscription list that you need to append once.